# Detecting a memory leak with Valgrind

Tags: c++, mysql, valgrind

I am writing a daemon in C++, it has a simple task of inserting some events into a mysql database.

When I ran the top command I saw that the processe's memory needs increase, I thought I had a memory leak and I started using Valgrind

I ran valgrind as this:

> valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes
>   --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes ./my_app

I get the following report:

```
==17045== 128 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 11
==17045==    at 0x402A629: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==17045==    by 0x40AAB63: my_thread_init (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17045==    by 0x40AAE43: my_thread_global_init (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17045==    by 0x40A92D7: my_init (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17045==    by 0x40863FA: mysql_server_init (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17045==    by 0x4087B28: mysql_init (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==17045==    by 0x8049890: write_db(std::string, std::string, std::string) (Listener.cpp:76)
==17045==    by 0x804A692: SocketListener(void*) (Listener.cpp:182)
==17045==    by 0x4052D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==17045==    by 0x4582D3D: clone (clone.S:130)
```

The function write_db is this:

```
void write_db(std::string userid,std::string zona,std::string eveniment)
{
    try
    {
    MYSQL * connect;
    connect = mysql_init(NULL);
    connect = mysql_real_connect(connect,"127.0.0.1","myusr","mypwd","mytbl",0,NULL,0);
    std::string stmt = "INSERT INTO t_evenimente(placaid,codev,zona,cand) VALUES(\"" + userid + "\"," + eveniment + ",\"" + zona + "\",NOW())";
    std::cout << stmt << std::endl;
    mysql_query(connect,stmt.c_str());
    mysql_close(connect);
    std::cout << "Inserat eveniment obiectiv " << userid << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout <<"Exceptie MYSQL" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Where is the memory leak ? I am using mysql_init and close as the documentation says...Could it be a false positive ?

Comment: There's potential for a memory leak if `mysql_real_connect()` returns `NULL`. You've then lost the pointer to the object returned by `mysql_init()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `connect` only inside your function, it's easier not to allocate it dynamically and risk a memory leak (most likely the one you're seeing). Also, the MySQL API is a C API and does not throw any exceptions for you to catch, which will simplify what you have now down to something like;

```
void write_db(std::string userid,std::string zona,std::string eveniment)
{
    MYSQL connect;
    mysql_init(&connect);
    mysql_real_connect(&connect,"127.0.0.1","myusr","mypwd","mytbl",0,NULL,0);
    std::string stmt = "INSERT INTO t_evenimente(placaid,codev,zona,cand) VALUES(\"" + userid + "\"," + eveniment + ",\"" + zona + "\",NOW())";
    std::cout << stmt << std::endl;
    mysql_query(&connect,stmt.c_str());
    mysql_close(&connect);
    std::cout << "Inserat eveniment obiectiv " << userid << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, that still leaves out error handling, which you'll need to add back.

Comment: @opc0de If the error is in the same place and only shows up on the first call, it would seem to be something internal to the MySQL library (ie can most likely be handled as a false positive) Does it show up once for every call to the function or just once at the first call to mysql_init?

Comment: every call ... I think is a false positive

Answer (score 1):

mysql_init returns a heap allocated object which needs to be freed by mysql_close. In the case when something in between mysql_init and mysql_close throws an exception, you never call close. Quick fix - add mysql_close to the catch block. Better fix - learn about/use RAII.

As Angew pointed out, it's actually probably more likely you are leaking the connection when you call mysql_real_connect (unless you are seeing your exception text in the log). You could use RAII to avoid this too.

Comment: You're partially right. "partially", because this seams to be the C API and there are no exceptions here. Most likely, some of the functions between `mysql_init` and `mysql_close` fails and invalidates the "handle".

Comment: Yeh, I realised after reading Angew's comment. Still waking up :)